# Can you get demoted to your previous position if that position is already filled?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

If you have been promoted to a higher position and now that’s position is getting eliminated, Can you get demoted to your previous position ( manager) if that’s position has been advertised and already filled?

Comment: Of course it can happen, but whether the company wants to do this, and what the process for that is, is completely up to them.

Comment: Please stop reposting closed questions. Fix the existing question instead.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have been promoted to a higher position and now that’s position
>   is getting eliminated, Can you get demoted to your previous position (
>   manager) if that’s position has been advertised and already filled?

Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody likes to be demoted. It can be painful on many levels. It can cost you money. It can be embarrassing. It can be confusing becasue everybody is unsure how to treat you in your new (old) position.

The alternative is for the company to say that we have enough employees at your former level, so we are letting you go.

Answer (score 0):

This would be rare, firstly the replacement manager would have a contract which would cause problems unless they are also being moved. Secondly it would cause potential morale issues for all concerned.